# Why I am not able to use a nested loop in a list of lists?

Tags: python-3.x, list, python-3.7

I am trying to solve a project from the book `Automate the boring stuff with Python`, chapter 4, `Project:Character picture grid`.

I am not able to loop through the code and print the pattern the book says. Here is my code:

```
gridlines = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],  # 0, 0
             ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
             ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
             ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
             ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
             ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
             ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
             ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
             ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

def grid_line(grid_func):
    for i in grid_func[0:8]:
        for grid_functioning in grid_func[0:5]:
                print(i, end='')

grid_line(gridlines)
```

The book is saying me to print this pattern:

```
..OO.OO..
.OOOOOOO.
.OOOOOOO.
..OOOOO..
...OOO...
....O....
```

Comment: Please let me know if there is any issues with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That pattern seems to be starting at the top left and initially going *down* rather than across<sup>(a)</sup>. That means you cannot process each column within a row but must instead process each row within a column.

Assuming, it's guaranteed to be rectangular, that can be done with<sup>(b)</sup>:

```
def grid_line(grid_func):
    for index in range(len(grid_func[0])): # square: do each column
        for row in grid_func:              # do each row within that column
            print(row[index], end="")      # output the cell, no line feed
        print()                            # go to next line after column
```

You'll notice I've removed the `[0:n]` bits since you don't need a slice, the entire row/column should be used. In any case, the `5` and `8` values you had were wrong, since the `n` is one *beyond* what you want to process, so you would have skipped the final row/column.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Technically, it *could* start at bottom left and go up (since it's symmetrical) but I've opted for the simpler case.

---

<sup>(b)</sup> It could *also* be done with the more Pythonic list comprehension and string join method below, but I'd probably hold off on that until you're a bit more comfortable with the language :-)

```
def grid_line(grid):
    print("\n".join(["".join([row[idx] for row in grid]) for idx in range(len(grid[0]))]))
```